# Register a control from another project asp C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net

I am unable to register my control from another project in my current project. I have a commoncontrols project and a controlpanel project now how can i get the usercontrols from the commoncontrols project?

The controlname is ucReg.ascx.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, a .ascx is not an asp control.

Comment: There must be :) I have about 150 of them in my project. It is a usercontrol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great guide how to use a user controls / page library:

> http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/28/423888.aspx

(By the way, you're using ASP.NET, not ASP)

Hope that helps.